# Is it possible to break word in space in AG Grid Wrap text

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

i am using Ag Grid in react web app.
The problem is that i need to display very long texts.
When i used `wrapText={true}` and `autoHeight={true}` properties everything devides in to lines like it supposed to.
Although most of the time text line break happens on the some word, even though there are plenty of space to break word on spaces.

```
<AgGridColumn
   headerName={'content'}
   editable={true}
   field="content"
   flex={1}
   wrapText={true}
   autoHeight={true} />
```

I was wondering is there are some ways to make line brake on spaces?

Comment: refer to [this](https://blog.ag-grid.com/wrapping-column-header-text/) blog.

Comment: Thank you i alredy  read this blog before making a question.
None of that didn't work, i even found the same problem i face, on their example tables.
I was just wondering maybe there are anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> columnDefs = [
> { field: 'fieldName', wrapText: true, autoHeight: true,
> cellRender: (params) => {
> return (
> <div style={{ wordBreak: "break-word" }}>
> { params.value }
>
> )
> }
> }
> ]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

I cheated and just added this to the page to overcome the shortcoming

```
.ag-cell-wrap-text {
      word-break: break-word;
}
```

but you could probably target it better if you wanted to, I have yet to see any negative side effects but that doesn't mean there isn't any.